# Can I create a .NET 4.0 application in Visual Stduio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a visual studio 2008.

I have downloaded and installed a .NET 4.0 package.

But I still can't create a .net 4.0 applications. VS 2008 shows it can only create 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. .NET 4.0 can only be used with Visual Studio 2010.

Visual Studio 2008 could target 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 because there were all based on the same runtime and language (3.0 and 3.5 were essentially additional libraries and updated compilers). 4.0 however is a different runtime.

Answer (score 0):

yes in VS 2008 you can't able to create .Net 4.0 applications.For that you need VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

That's because VS2008 doesn't support .NET 4 as a target platform. For that you need either VS2010 or just use the compiler that ships with the framework (but then you will not have an IDE).